# 3 divs in container responsive to width of page

Tags: css, html

I have been fiddling with this issue all day now. I need to create a 3 column design where the middle div has a fixed width and the left/right divs are dynamic (responsive to the width of page). For example:

```
#container {
float:left;
width:100%;
}

#left {
min-width: 200px;
width: 100%;
}

#middle {
width: 250px;
}

#right {
min-width: 200px;
width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        Left column should expand with the width of the browser - with a min-width.
    </div>

    <div id="middle">
        Middle column with fixed width.
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        Right column should expand with the width of the browser - with a min-width.
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/2jGAe/
Can you help me solve this styling issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to use :

```
#container > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

with no width on the #left and #right divs.  See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2jGAe/1/).

Comment: The middle div goes less than 200px, why? Try shrinking the width of the screen to see.

Comment: You'll need to add `min-width: 250px;` to the `#middle` selector so that it doesn't shrink!

Comment: This is a rather interesting approach. How compatible is this for browsers? I have come across other ways to achieve this, but this is the first time I see this solution...

Comment: @Gary Woods The [caniuse.com website](http://caniuse.com/css-table) is useful for that.

Comment: @maxime how do I separate the DIVs? I tried separating the divs with 20px but the background color is kept, no matter if I use padding or margin. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Shame that IE7 is not supported with this :( Damn you IE.

Comment: @henrik You can use `border-spacing` on the container div.  See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2jGAe/7/).  This applies a border to all cells.  I'm not sure if there's a way to target specific cells.

Comment: Final question before I accept this as correct answer. What condition could I add in the CSS for IE7 users? I believe that I have come across such thing before... This condition should set a fixed with for all divs.

Comment: I did not find any interesting hacks.  You can always add an extra css file only for IE7 and set widths in %.  IE7 usage is below 5% right now. (Sources [1](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php), [2](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201109-201209))

Comment: This was what I was referring to: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/